# Problem with React "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: reactjs

Trying to add the login function to the login button but for some reason it says that "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" and I have no idea how to fix it.

I have added the `window.onload = function(){}` which worked on my other component but doesn't work on this one.

Problem is in this part.

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
    UserLogin();
})
}
```

and here is the whole code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './Config';
//import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



function UserLogin(){
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        //var errorCode = error.code;
        //var errorMessage = error.message;
      });
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
        UserLogin();
    })
}


function Login(){
    return(
        <div class="start">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="input">
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email"></input>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
                <button id="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login is likely not rendered yet when `window.onload` is called.

Why not just use the onClick property on the button?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './Config';
//import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



function UserLogin(){
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        //var errorCode = error.code;
        //var errorMessage = error.message;
      });
}

function Login(){
    return(
        <div class="start">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="input">
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email"></input>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
                <button id="submit" onClick={UserLogin}>Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `UserLogin` function should get called automatically when your component finishes loading, then you can make use of [`Hooks`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) **(Added in React 16.8)**.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';


function Login(){
    useEffect(() => {
      UserLogin();
    });
    return(
        <div class="start">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="input">
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email"></input>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
                <button id="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```